# Bootstrap 5 Padding throwing off Aspect Ratio For Group of Images

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, responsiveness

I'm having a hard time wrangling with 3 images that are in a 1 row spanning / 2 row 2 column layout (please view picture). I can get it to look perfect at one resolution, but viewing it in other breakpoints, the ratio become all wrong because of static padding size.

Code:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-5 text-center">
          <img class="img-fluid ratio ratio-1x1" src="/assets/mood1-8dc4fbf7f86401c523a66983158d7366ce7b41c40b9b568c9a79f2455ae983f4.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 d-flex flex-column">
          <img class="img-fluid d-none d-md-block mb-2 ratio ratio-16x9" src="/assets/mood2-6b77bce1c8930fd5638d4d982b0c01b357dc38d6212588db2ef12ef67dc8f0e4.png">
          <img class="img-fluid d-none d-md-block mt-2 ratio ratio-16x9" src="/assets/mood3-1baca87fe953122237237cbe216e5574d0b6b8b0af20b14057c93281f10d426b.png">
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </section>
```

XXL:

[image: 3 photos large]

Note how the bottom and top of the images in both columns line up perfectly.

Medium:

[image: 3 photos medium]

Note how the bottom no longer lines up. The padding is not being responsive, throwing the ratios off. Any ideas to better approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding **`h-100`** to your image may help.

You can also use [bootstrap gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/) here `gx-3`, to set your gutters spacing as your needs

Result.

[image]

*Expand snippet to see result*

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center gx-3">
        <div class="col-5 text-center">
          <img class="img-fluid ratio ratio-1x1 h-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554080353-a576cf803bda?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 d-flex flex-column">
          <img class="img-fluid d-none d-md-block mb-2 ratio ratio-16x9 h-100" src="https://apprendre-la-photo.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/photo-vitesse-obturation-elevee_laurent-breillat-1200x900.jpg">
          <img class="img-fluid d-none d-md-block mt-2 ratio ratio-16x9 h-100" src="https://www.designer.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/1-1024x698.png">
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you! FYI, ratio and ratio-16x9 seem to be ignored. I removed those two and just used h-100 and it all works. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. You can rewrite ratio css also.. IF my answer is ok, think about me :)