# Bootstrap 5 h-100 Works for Chrome, fails for Safari for group of images

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, bootstrap-5

Please reference question: [Bootstrap 5 Padding throwing off Aspect Ratio For Group of Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69744683/bootstrap-5-padding-throwing-off-aspect-ratio-for-group-of-images/69744763?noredirect=1#comment123281659_69744763)

The solution of applying `h-100` works perfectly for Chrome. However, when I view the solution in safari, the image does not maintain its aspect ratio but is stretched to be many 2x the image size while staying the same width. Any idea what is causing this and how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I removed `ratio` class when it did not appear to do anything in Chrome. Apparently, it is very much necessary to maintain the proper aspect ratio for Safari. Having both `ratio h-100` in the class on the images fixed the issue.